# Can't clear UserProfile <-> Role relation (using Entity Framework 5 and MVC 4)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Using Entity Framework 5, MVC 4 and the CheckBoxList 1.4.4.3-beta2 from CodeProject, I am simply trying to clear a UserProfile objects Roles relation in an many-to-many relation.

UserProfileController (reduced - doesn't save scalar properties and selected roles):

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit(int identifier)
    {
        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        using(var userProfileRepository = new UserProfileRepository(unitOfWork))
        {
            UserProfile user = userProfileRepository.AllIncluding(u => u.Roles).Single(u => u.UserId == identifier);
            UserProfileViewModel viewModel;
            using (var roleRepository = new RoleRepository(unitOfWork))
            {
                viewModel = new UserProfileViewModel()
                                {
                                    AllRoles = roleRepository.All.ToList(),
                                    UserProfile = user
                                };
            }
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfileViewModel viewModel, string[] roleIds)
    {
        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        using (var userProfileRepository = new UserProfileRepository(unitOfWork))
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = userProfileRepository.AllIncluding(u => u.Roles).Single(u => u.UserId == viewModel.UserProfile.UserId);
                user.Roles.Clear();
                userProfileRepository.InsertOrUpdate(user);
                unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

UserProfileRepository (and RoleRepository) are standard scaffolded repositories:

```
    public void InsertOrUpdate(UserProfile userprofile)
    {
        if (userprofile.UserId == default(int)) {
            // New entity
            context.UserProfiles.Add(userprofile);
        } else {
            //// Existing entity
            context.Entry(userprofile).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

UserProfile:

```
public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

Role:

```
public ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
```

I get no exceptions but also no updates to the database are performed. Could it be caused by the authentication provider (SimpleMembershipProvider) which is using the same db tables? Should I implement a custom membership provider? I have several other many-to-many relations in my application all made up the same way as this and they all work like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug I made when overriding the Equals method on UserProfile making all comparisons return false.